# How to guarantee the ordering of a for each loop on an object in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Suppose I have a function that I want to use to display an object's properties, in sorted order:

```
function showObject(obj:Object) {
    for ( var key in obj ) {
        trace("key: " + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

I understand that this is not guaranteed to be in any particular order; What's the best way to do this, but guarantee sorted order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
function showObject(obj:Object) {
    var keys:Array = new Array();
    var key;
    for ( key in obj ) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
    keys.sort();
    for ( key in obj ) {
        trace(key + ": " + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I just didn't know if there was a better way. Thanks.

Comment: @Fragsworth, there may be, but if it's just debugging code (as your using `trace` suggests), then it's probably a waste of time trying to optimize it. If you need better performance, then you'll probably need a different data structure that's designed for ordering information.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  It's a hashing algorithm, and for...in specifically is used to enumerate dynamic (eg hashed) properties.  If you need it to return an ordered list, you should use an Array or create an ordered Hash class that you can iterate through sequentially.  Just understand that you won't be able to use a for...in loop to do it.  You have to build the iterator to handle that logic itself and simply call .next() on it to have it return the next item in sequence.